# Policy not working when invoking method that returns true or false di per se

Tags: laravel, authorization, policy

Strange thing:

I have this method to check if a user voted for an item to be added to the DB:

```
   /**
     *
     * checks if User already voted for item
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function wasVotedByUser()
    {

        $voted = $this->item_votes()->where('user_id' , Auth::id())->first();

        if(!is_null($voted)){

            return(true);

        } else {

            return (false);
        }
    }
```

so this already returns true or false.
I tried to add it to a policy to invoke after the user tries to vote:

```
public function voteModel(User $user, Item $item)
{
    //user can't vote it's own inserted data
    if($user->id == $item->user_id ){

        return false;

    }else{
        // this should return true or false
        return $item->wasVotedByUser();

    }

}
```

however this way it doesn't work while it works like this:

```
public function voteModel(User $user, Item $item)
{

    if($user->id == $item->user_id ){

        return false;

    }else{

        if($item->wasVotedByUser()){

            return false;

        }else{

            return true;

        }

    }

}
```

any idea why?

Comment: Debug for yourself, put `dd('I am here!');` inside the `wasVotedByUser()` method and see yourself if its being called at all. Obviously you have some kind of logic error... so `dd` until you find it.

Comment: I already tried to dd the method and it returns true or false as expected

Comment: Do you have any filters applied in policy? (show whole policy file).

Comment: No , there are no filters and the code I posted is what's in the policy, just that

Comment: That means you need to do more debugging yourself using `dd()`. There is no way anyone here can debug it for you...

Comment: I tried with this code to see what exactly is the method returning and it's returning false (or true). So I'm still baffled: `$model = Model::findOrFail(3);

        return response()->json(array('voted' => $model->wasVotedByUser()));` ---> this returns: {"voted":false}

Comment: I got it, what a moron! if I return item->wasVotedByUser(); and the user didn't vote that will return false hence the authorization will fail.

Comment: Good for you....